# Ajaxify Mediaelemet.js

Tags: ajax, wordpress, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm using mediaelemetjs to make audio playlists which is fine on [my wordpress website](https://devoiders.com/music/the-keeper) , but it doesn't load with ajax, I also installed a plugin named WaveSurfer to generate waveform(it works with mediaelementjs) but still doesn't load when I enable Ajax!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I don't have any code, the theme I purchased has an option in misc that enables ajax, and it seems it's a mediaelementjs issue with ajax.
Which code you want me to share?